# Difference between 大兄弟 and 小伙子

Tags: meaning, mandarin, usage, vocabulary

Difference between 大兄弟 and 小伙子.

Under which condition should we use one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

小伙子 is *young guy*. It's a generic term to address a young man.

大兄弟 is used in north, which sounds pretty folksy. It's used to address a man and is said by some older people. Sometimes, we make a joke to address a guy as 大兄弟.

Comment: 小伙子 is also used to refer to (not necessarily address) a young male, see comment #1